# algebraic data type data Nat = Zero | S Nat

Tags: haskell

we started know with  algebraic data types. As an example we have :

```
add ::  Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add a Zero = a
add a (S b) = add (S a) b

add' ::  Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add' a Zero  = a
add' a (S b) = S (add' a b)
```

WHat is that suppose to mean? okay, add a Zero = a I guess it's clear.
But add a (S b) = add (S a) b ? and add' ?

thank you very much ;)

Comment: Have you experimented with these in `ghci`?

Comment: These are two different implementations of addition, hence the two different names (`add`, `add'`). The meaning of `add a (S b) = add (S a) b` is sort of "if the second argument is nonzero, increment the first argument and decrement the second argument."

Comment: Perhaps it will help if you read `S` as `1+`, so that `S b` is `1+b`. Then `add a (1+b) = add (1+a) b` looks quite readable to me, as well as `add' a (1+b) = 1+(add' a b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you are teaching a child how to add numbers who only knows counting.

First:
Adding 3 and 2 equals adding 4 and 1, equals adding 5 and 0, where we know the answer is 5.

Second:
Adding 3 and 2 is finding the next number after adding 3 and 1, which is the next next number after adding 3 and 0.  So, the answer is counting up twice on 3.